# How do you append a char[256] to the contents of an edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi, char, append, lpstr

I am working on a small GUI calculator project and I need to append something to the contents of an edit control. The function I am currently using is:

```
int CharControl = 256;

void AddToEditMainText(char WhatToAdd[CharControl]) {
    char CurrText[CharControl] = "";
    GetDlgItemText(MainWindow, EDIT_MAIN, CurrText, CharControl);
    char NewText[CharControl] = "";
    malloc(strlen(NewText) + strlen(WhatToAdd) + 1);
    strcpy_s(NewText, CurrText);
    strcat_s(NewText, WhatToAdd);
    SendMessage(EditMain, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, LPARAM((LPCSTR)&NewText));
}
```

I'm relatively new to C++, so this is my first  GUI project. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `WM_SETTEXT` will replace the entire contents. To append, you can position the cursor at the end with `EM_SETSEL` and then use `EM_REPLACESEL` to append.

Comment: Don't use Code::Blocks - it's notorious for using ill-fated defaults. Windows NT has been UTF-16 since its inception. Don't use `char`s - `wchar_t` is where it's at.

Comment: I'm not using code::blocks, I'm using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change a few things:

```
void AddToEditMainText(char *WhatToAdd)
```

In the context of function parameters, a character array and a pointer is the same thing. Even if the passed parameter is a char array of a given length, it doesn't matter, so let's not confuse things.

But we can do even better. This question is tagged C++, not C. In C++, we'd like to think we've progressed a bit above low-level byte flinging. When we're talking strings, we're now talking std::string:

```
void AddToEditMainText(const std::string &WhatToAdd)
```

I'm not very familiar with MS-Windows API, but it seems obvious that "GetDlgItemText" is a C API function that pulls text from an existing dialog control. Not sure if you're guaranteed that the returned string will be less, or will be truncated to a 256 byte buffer. That's actually an important point, but, for an introductory environment for C++, that's not important.

The char buffer used by GetDlgItemText() is so ... C-ish. A char buffer is such a quaint concept in C++. After getDlgItemText returns, let's not waste any time, and get it into a nice, pretty, std::string:

```
std::string CurrTextStr=CurrText;
```

Now, again, in C++ we don't have to bother with petty details like allocating memory, and making sure to free it after use. std::string will do it for us:

```
std::string combinedString=CurrTextStr + WhatToAdd;
```

Wasn't this easy? No need to calculate sizes of various buffers. That's so ...last century. We're in the modern age, where the "+" operator will do it for us. And, finally, since SendMessage() is another quaint C library API, and we have to talk down to its level, I suppose...

```
SendMessage(EditMain, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, LPARAM((LPCSTR)combinedString.c_str()));
```

Oh, and don't forget to stick a "#include <string>" somewhere at the top, to pull in the definition of std::string.

Comment: That cast to `LPCSTR` just raises my suspicion until I realize it's just casting to the same type as the operand.

Comment: Using references to C++ objects in an interface is not something I would call *"doing even better"*. Doing so severely limits the applicability. You just went from *"can be invoked from just about any programming language in the universe"* to *"only use from C++, using this particular compiler, and this particular CRT, and provide **exactly** these compiler options"*. Just leave it at `const char*` and move on.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the result of `malloc()` to anything, so you are leaking memory.  You should be doing something more like this instead:

```
void AddToEditMainText(char *WhatToAdd)
{
    int iLen = GetWindowTextLen(EditMain) + strlen(WhatToAdd) + 1;
    char *NewText = malloc(iLen);
    if (NewText)
    {
        GetWindowText(EditMain, NewText, iLen);
        strcat_s(NewText, iLen, WhatToAdd);
        SetWindowText(EditMain, NewText);
        free(NewText);
    }
}
```

I would suggest a different approach that does not require you to retrieve the current text before appending to it:

```
void AddToEditMainText(char *WhatToAdd)
{
    DWORD dwStart, dwEnd;
    SendMessage(EditMain, EM_GETSEL, WPARAM(&dwStart), LPARAM(&dwEnd));
    int iLen = GetWindowTextLength(EditMain);
    SendMessage(EditMain, EM_SETSEL, iLen, iLen);
    SendMessage(EditMain, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, LPARAM(WhatToAdd));
    SendMessage(EditMain, EM_SETSEL, WPARAM(dwStart), LPARAM(dwEnd));
}
```

Comment: Similarly, at a later stage, I will have to code some sort of backspace method. I found using your method of EM_SETSEL and EM_REPLACESEL to be useful, so is there a way to make a backspace function using that?

Comment: Simply use `EM_SETSEL` to select the last character and then `EM_REPLACESEL` it with a blank string.